# Train model in batches using fit_generator

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My model has 100 000 training samples of images, how do I modify my code below to train it in batches? With model.fit_generator I have to specify this inside the generator function:

```
def data_generator(descriptions, features, n_step, max_sequence):
    # loop until we finish training
    while 1:
        # loop over photo identifiers in the dataset
        for i in range(0, len(descriptions), n_step):
            Ximages, XSeq, y = list(), list(),list()
            for j in range(i, min(len(descriptions), i+n_step)):
                image = features[j]
                # retrieve text input
                desc = descriptions[j]
                # generate input-output pairs
                in_img, in_seq, out_word = preprocess_data([desc], [image], max_sequence)
                for k in range(len(in_img)):
                    Ximages.append(in_img[k])
                    XSeq.append(in_seq[k])
                    y.append(out_word[k])
            # yield this batch of samples to the model
            yield [[array(Ximages), array(XSeq)], array(y)]
```

My `model.fit_generator` code:

```
model.fit_generator(data_generator(texts, train_features, 1, 150), 
                    steps_per_epoch=1500, epochs=50, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=1)
```

Any assistance would be great, I'm training on a cloud 16GB V100 Tesla

Edit: My image caption model creates a training sample for each token in the DSL(250 tokens). With a dataset of 50 images (equivalent to 12500 training samples) and a batch size of 1, I get an OOM. With about 32 (equivalent to 8000 samples and a batch size of 1 it trains just fine.) My question is can I optimize my code better, or is my only option to use multiple GPUs?

Fix:

Steps_per_epoch must be equal to ceil(num_samples / batch_size), so if the dataset has 1500 samples, steps_per_epoch should be equal to 1500. I also reduced my LSTM sliding window from 48 to 24

> steps_per_epoch: Integer. Total number of steps (batches of samples)
>   to yield from generator before declaring one epoch finished and
>   starting the next epoch. It should typically be equal to
>   ceil(num_samples / batch_size). Optional for Sequence: if unspecified,
>   will use the len(generator) as a number of steps.

Comment: It's already in batches. Each `yield` is a batch.

Comment: How do I control the batch size?

Comment: If the answer below is not enough, you should explain your question properly. That answers exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So are you saying that the code cannot be optimized. The only solution is to train in multiple V100 GPU's?

Comment: What is your question? You asked how to change batch size.

Comment: With a dataset of 50 images (equivalent to 12500 training samples) and a batch size of 1, I get an OOM. With about 32 (equivalent to 8000 samples and a batch size of 1 it trains just fine.) My question is can I optimize my code, or is my only option to use multiple GPUs?

Comment: You should detail your problem in the question then. You should test the generator, see the batch size. I don't understand how the size of the dataset is giving you an OOM unless you're sending the entire dataset to the model, which is not done by generators. You must inspect your code and see where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generators already return batches.

Every `yield` is a batch. It's totally up to you to design the generator with the batches the way you want.

In your code, the batch size is `n_step`.

Comment: I always get an OOM, for example, changing n_step to 32 gives me: Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 22.79GiB.

Comment: Well.... reduce the batch size then. Use a smaller `n_step`. Try 16, 8, etc.

Comment: You may also set a `max_queue_size` in `fit_generator`, because the images it loads will be waiting in the queue and use your memory, usually the CPU memory.

Comment: Ok cool let me try, i reduced to n_step = 8 and it allocated 8GB this time. Will try a lower number

Comment: Not winning, I get OOM even at 1. I'm only able to train the model if I manually load 32 actual samples. My image caption model multiplies the image by the number of tokens in the vocabulary

Comment: Daniel is right. You must be doing something wrong when getting OOM. It is actually impossible to get OOM at 1 and successfully manually load 32 actual samples.

Comment: My model creates a training sample for each token in the DSL of 200 tokens, so with average of 250 tokens per sample, 1 sample is equivalent to 250 training samples. With 1000 total images in my dataset i have the equivalent to 250k training samples

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper way of using generators: Make a generator that yields individual datums. Create a `Dataset` from it and use `batch` method on that object. Tune the parameter to find the largest batch size that won't cause an OOM.

```
def data_generator(descriptions, features, max_sequence):
    def _gen():
        for img, seq, word in zip(*preprocess_data(descriptions, features, max_sequence)):
            yield {'image': in_img, 'seq': seq}, wo
    return _gen    


ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    data_generator(descriptions, features, max_sequence),
    output_types=({'image': tf.float32, 'seq': tf.float32}, tf.int32),
    output_shapes=({
            'image': tf.TensorShape([blah, blah]),
            'seq': tf.TensorShape([blah, blah]),
        },
        tf.TensorShape([balh])
    )
)

ds = ds.batch(n_step)
```